# How to Target ES6 for Server and ES5 for Client

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, tsconfig

I am creating a project with node on the server and Angular 2 on the client. I want to use Typescript across the entire project. I would like to target ES6 for the server, since node supports it, but ES5 for the client. Currently my directory structure looks something like this.

```
├── app.js
├── something.js
├── tsconfig.json
├── wwwroot
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── main.ts
│   ├── components
│   │   ├── mycomponent.ts
```

I want everything above `wwwroot` to target ES6, but everything inside of `wwwroot` to target ES5. I tried putting a second `tsconfig.json` inside the `wwwroot` folder, but that didn't seem to work. I am using Atom's autocompile feature, if that is of any relevance.

Comment: Take a look to https://github.com/angular/angular-cli as i see for you it should be a good fit since you will be able to start development fast and later if you need you can extend. But i am not sure if there is ES6 option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use babel to transpile es6 javascript to whatever flavor of ecmascript you desire.

http://babeljs.io/

Comment: Are you saying I should transpile everything to es6, then use babel to transpile the client side code to es5?

Comment: Basically  yes. Typescript will compile down to es6, and then babel will take that to es5. It's a little odd, but you have a very specific scenario

Comment: It looks like typescript supports transpiling es5 code, but I'm not familiar with the process. See this : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html. Specifically the --lib flag

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar situation, and what I'm doing is:

```
- project-root
  - scripts
    - tsconfig.json
  - wwwroot
    - scripts
      - tsconfig.json
    - html
      - index.html
    - styles
      - index.css
```

The `scripts/tsconfig.json` targets `es6` for the server, and the `wwwroot/scripts/tsconfig.json` targets `es5` for the client.

Comment: The auto compile feature just ignored the lower `tsconfig.json` when I tried this. Is there one tsc command you can run to compile both?

Comment: No, you need to compile them differently, but if your IDE supports having multiple `tsconfig.json` files then you shouldn't have a problem. In my current project I have 4 different ones and it works great. I'm working with webstorm

Answer (score 0):

You can use Babel to transpile to es5 what nodejs does not already implement, using the preset `"babel-preset-es2015-node6"`.

You can transpile only the directories that you want to es5 using for example a script in your node package.json:

```
"prestart": "babel server-source --out-dir dist/source"
```