# Why would I use TypeScript and Babel together?

Tags: javascript, typescript, build, automation, babeljs

We have in-house written build automation running on NPM and NodeJS. I'm fully comfortable with automating some transform steps to get TypeScript and Babel working together. I just wonder what the benefit will be. Can anyone tell me? It would appear that since TS has added support for ES6 that you don't really need Babel. The one thing that seems probable is Babel supporting new features sooner, but TS doesn't seem to be too far behind at the moment.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't think that other question compares typescript to babel.

Comment: Ahh but the answer is in there. Thanks :)

Comment: There's enough slippage between this question and the other that they're not dupes. You might use Babel & TS to [target two platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40479782/how-to-target-es6-for-server-and-es5-for-client).  You might use them to, apparently, [enable tree-shaking, as Lekhnath answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44021016/1028230). Maybe TS compilation used to be a significant subset of a good es6 transpiler, but that tack becomes less useful the further out we get from the linked question, originally asked in 2014. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In my opinion you transpile TypeScript code to ES6 by using `typescript` and then re-transpile it to `es5/es3` using `babel` to use in most javascript run times. Now because typescript compiler gives you es6 javascript you can do [`tree-shaking`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) which is only supported for es6 module. And after tree-shaking your `es6 javascript` you can now compile it down to `es5` to be able to used by most of the javascript run times out there.

Basically

1. Compile ts to js-es6

**tsconfig**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6"
  }
}
```

2. tree shake or dead code elimination in es6 javascript

**Tree Shaking**
Using rollup etc

3. Transpile to es5 javascript to be able to run in most of the javascript runtimes

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es-2015",
    "stage-2"
  ]
}
```

Comment: [TypeScript Compiler](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) allows to specify `--target ES5` also, would in that case babel be required?

Comment: @SandeepKumar Babel is not required to compile typescript code to javascript. But sometimes you may want to use features that are not yet approved in ES specifications. For example : In `ES6`/`ES-2015` you cannot define class properties. ie `class User{ role = 'administrator' }` is not valid, but if you want to use this feature  now in `ES6` you will need `babel` and its plugin called `transform-class-properties`.

Comment: @SandeepKumar In above example I've used `stage-2` preset in `.babelrc` which means we are able to use all proposed features for `ES` specification that are currently in `stage-2` but are not part of `ES-2015` specification.

Comment: @Lekhnath I don't think you get the question. He meant that you can directly compile typescript to ES3, why should we use babel in that case?

Comment: @Lekhnath LoL I think its the opposite. So cases you described `Babel` is totally useless if you use `TS`, that's the short answer instead of writing 250 words answer + comments which had no logical conclusion.

From [ts docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/babel-with-typescript.html).

Is your build output mostly the same as your source input files? Use `tsc`
Do you need a build pipeline with multiple potential outputs? Use `babel` for transpiling and `tsc` for type checking

Comment: Me too, i don't know why i have to use babel in this case, i can put "target:es5" option in tsconfig. The code will be compile to es5. Why do you need compile to es6 with "tsc" and then use babel to take them into es5, it takes more one step.

Comment: Agree with @Simba . I think typscript compiler can directly convert ts to es5.  Why need babel?